# combobox display object children member

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox

I'm trying to fill a ComboBox using a list of objects. Each object of the list has another objects. I need to show "option.Dish.dish_name" in the comboBox DisplayMember and I need "option.option_id" in the comboBox ValueMember. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
foreach (Option option in optionList)
{
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add(option);
        this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Dish.dish_name";
        this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "option_id";
 }
```

The option class is an Entity Framework Entity, but is something like:

```
public class Option 
{
    private int option_id;
    private DateTime option_date;
    private Dish dish;
}

public class Dish
{
    private int dish_id;
    private String dish_name;
    private DateTime date_created;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

New problem: There is anyway to get that "new object" to use it later? I need another value, for example:

```
this.comboBox1.ItemsSource = optionList.Select(o=> new
{
    option_id = o.option_id, 
    dish_name = o.dish.dish_name, 
    date = o.dish_date
}).ToList();
```

and then use that object to get the "date" value?.

Comment: Can you show Dish class implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.comboBox1.ItemsSource =
        optionList.Select(o=> new{option_id = o.option_id, dish_name =o.dish.dish_name}).ToList();

this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "dish_name";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "option_id";
```

Comment: Hey Damith, there is anyway to get that "new object" to use it later? I need another value, for example:

this.comboBox1.ItemsSource =
        optionList.Select(o=> new{option_id = o.option_id, dish_name =o.dish.dish_name, date = o.dish_date}).ToList();

and then use that object to get the "date" value.